# CountIfs with Multiple Criteria?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table like this:

```
Date Paid   Days Late   Date Paid   Days Late   Date Paid   Days Late   Date Paid   Days Late   Date Paid   Days Late   Date Paid   Days Late
        Utilities       Admin       Utilities       Admin       Utilities       Admin   
    Company January January January January February    February    February    February    March   March   March   March
    Wayne Enterprises   2/15/2016   5   10-Feb  0   3/11/2016   1           4/15/2016   5   4/25/2016   15
    Stark Industries    2/12/2016   3   2/8/2016    0   3/19/2016   10  3/8/2016    0   4/15/2016   5   4/1/2016    0
```

(I suggest though looking at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxip5.jpg) to see how it's laid out, as the pasting into here isn't very pretty, any tips? [Here's a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6MCvPI89QJ7kHkmPEUHKC0YPFvXlyGa4Rr4BbvdJ_s/edit?usp=sharing) to this on Google Spreadsheets).

How can I, in `N4`, create a formula that will count the number of months what have a late report (defined as any "Days Late" over 0).  Obviously, I can do this:

`=COUNTIFS(B1:M1,"Days Late",B4:M4,">0")`, which returns `4`.

For Wayne Enterprises, in March, both Utilities and Admin were paid late.  However, this should only count as 1 month.  How can I somehow add to my `CountIfs()` a statement that is like "if two values in the same month are greater than 0, treat as ONE month"?

I tried also doing something like:

`=COUNTIFS(B1:M1,"Days Late",B4:M4,">0")/COUNTIFS(B1:M1,"Days Late",B4:M4,">0")+1`

But that doesn't quite do the trick either.  Thanks for any ideas. (Of course, if `CountIfs()` isn't the best way, I'm open to any other formulas! I have a sneaking suspicion `SumProduct()` might be an alternative) I'd prefer a formula solution over VBA, but if absolutely necessary, we can do a UDF perhaps.

Edit: I could create yet another helper column that compares a single month's Utilities and Admin, and if one or both are late, put `1`, then just `Countif()` that column has `1` in it...but I'd rather not keep creating columns if I can help it, as I'll be doing this for 12 months.

Comment: You'll likely need to nest if statements within your Countif, but I'm on my iPad and don't have excel available to create example.

Comment: Dude, I am feeling lazy but I want to help.  could you like put this in a google sheet that I can copy and paste?

Comment: Try using this ....COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…) for as many checks as you need. This is from this tutorial...https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/10/excel-countifs-multiple-criteria/

Comment: @ScottCraner - [Here you are](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6MCvPI89QJ7kHkmPEUHKC0YPFvXlyGa4Rr4BbvdJ_s/edit?usp=sharing)!

Comment: @dinotom - That's what I was thinking, but what would the criteria look like to check if a cell in the same month, is greater than 1? That's the trouble spot for my brain.

Comment: For a given month criteria 1 is the cell under Utility and criteria 2 is the cell under Admin...Countifs(utilitydayslatecell, ">0", admindayslatecell, ">0"...

Comment: @BruceWayne  Nothing wrong with your question.  I was just noticing that when it comes up in the question list page, that the brief snippet of the question that they show is mainly the header from your sample data.  I have done this as well.  In the future you may want to have more of a summary of the question as your leader and save the sample data till the end.  Food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(($B4:$M4>0)*($B$1:$M$1="Days Late"),1/COUNTIFS($B$3:$M$3,$B$3:$M$3,$B4:$M4,">0",$B$1:$M$1,"Days Late")))
```

**Being an array formula it must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>** when exiting edit mode.  If done properly excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

As per your new data use this:

```
=SUM(IF(($B5:$BI5>0)*($B$1:$BI$1="Days past 10th of Following Month"),1/COUNTIFS($B$3:$BI$3,$B$3:$BI$3,$B5:$BI5,">0",$B$1:$BI$1,"Days past 10th of Following Month")))
```

The helper row of months in row 4 is not needed.

---

**EDIT #2**

My bad I forgot that when using formulas that return `""` will cause an error so lets put in a check for that:

```
=SUM(IF(($B5:$BI5<>"")*($B5:$BI5>0)*($B$1:$BI$1=$AS$1),1/COUNTIFS($B$3:$BI$3,$B$3:$BI$3,$B5:$BI5,">0",$B$1:$BI$1,$AS$1)))
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a `#DIV/0` error...Using the evaluator, it looks like the error comes in at the `CountIfs(...)` part at the end. Might it be this part, `COUNTIFS($B$3:$M$3,$B$3:$M$3,...`?

Comment: not sure,  That is what the SUM(IF()) portion should avoid.  It is working for me, did you try it on the test data?

Comment: I must confess, the test data was simplified. In reality, it's a bit more data. (I thought it would work just by expanding your ranges, but obviously not).  I'm going to edit the Google Sheet to be more reflective of what I have. Sorry Scott for the deception :P (give me say 5 minutes to update that SS).

Comment: (I've Updated the spreadsheet. The "End of Month" column just helps me calculate how many days past, FYI....hm, on second thought, I could just combine that into the original cells, so I can get rid of that helper column in each month.)

Comment: Use this `=SUM(IF(($B5:$BI5>0)*($B$1:$BI$1="Days past 10th of Following Month"),1/COUNTIFS($B$3:$BI$3,$B$3:$BI$3,$B5:$BI5,">0",$B$1:$BI$1,"Days past 10th of Following Month")))`

Comment: @BruceWayne I bet you were using row 4 when you changed mine, that will not work as those cells do not have data in the cells that is needed to make the formula work, use row 3 instead.

Comment: I changed the row, here's the formula I have: `=SUM(IF(($B5:$BI5>0)*($B$1:$BI$1=$BH$1),1/COUNTIFS($B$3:$BI$3,$B$3:$BI$3,$B5:$BI5,">0",$B$1:$BI$1,$BH$1)))`.  Edit: Tried the formula you just commented with, and same error.  For what it's worth, the cells that are "blank", some are formulas.

Comment: Your formula works for me even with formulas that return either "" or 0.  For the life of me I cannot get it to what you are showing.  Make sure that none of the cells in the three ranges are merged, it is the only reason I can think of.

Comment: @BruceWayne if you want email the workbook in which you are getting the error, scott.craner@gmail.com

Comment: I appreciate the offer to look at the workbook! I'm going to try and work it out (so I can learn too), but if I really can't get it, I'll send along.  I used the Formula Evaluator, and after this step is where I get `#DIV/0` errors for all the underlined info: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PfRzU.jpg). (I checked, and there are no merged cells in that range)

Comment: @BruceWayne the 0 in the first group should line up with the 0 in the second group.  There is some reason that the two criteria in the IF are not resolving correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112538/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-scott-craner).

Comment: Hayooo!! That did it, thanks a gabrillion my friend.  Was it mainly the adding of `If((B5:BI5<>"")` that did it? Sorry I didn't specify way sooner that the formulas could return `""`.  But for real, you earned that 20k!!! :D :D

Comment: @BruceWayne that was what it took and you had specified the condition and I swear I tested it but, I cannot argue with results.